# Doctrine FIxtures and Symfony2 Request scope

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, assetic

I want to create Article fixtures for my project which uses Doctrine2 and Symfony 2.2.

Here is how articles are created:

They don't link to images directly but instead they contain image names. Before saving an article my `ArticleManager` parses article text, finding image names, searching for those images in database and replacing image markup part with real image path, for example.

```
This is article content
typed in form
and it contains an
![Image description](Here is My Awesome Image Name)
```

Then when form is submitted and `ArticleManager->save($article)` is called, article manager changes image markup by real file **WEB** path:

```
This is article content
typed in form
![Image description](/path/to/my_awesome_image.png)
```

**The problem**: `ArticleManager` relies on `Assetic assets helper` service to build full web image paths and that service resides in `request` scope. On the other hand, `Doctrine fixtures` are ran from CLI so they can't access that service, making me unable to get image paths when loading article fixture.

Can anyone suggest me the least **hackish** way of tackling this problem?

Comment: What exception message do you get when trying to use assetic?

Comment: Where are you storing you those pictures? In a public folder?

Comment: @piotrekkr I get ` [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException]                          
  You cannot create a service ("piflex_website.article.manager") of an inactive scope ("request").`

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes, I store them under `web/configurable/path` folder. What are you aiming for? Is there a way to find out web path without $request? Note that website can reside in subdirectory so I can't just use absolute path like "/configurable/path/image.png".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @cheesemacfly's comment I digged a bit and realized that since my Images are stored in public folder I don't have to use assetic at all!

Instead of using it to create Image URLs I injected `router` service into my `ArticleManager` and generated URLs this way:

```
$baseRoute = $this->router->getContext()->getBaseUrl();

$appFiles = array('/app.php', '/app_dev.php');
$baseRoute = str_replace($appFiles, '', $baseRoute);

$imageDocumentRoute = $baseRoute . '/' . $imageDocument->getWebPath();
```

`imageDocument->getWebPath()` returns image name appended to subfolder where images are saved. E.g. `subweb/path/imagename.png`.

Comment: That's what I was aiming for :)